# How to animate the word one by one using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I need to animate the word "Update". I would like the word's letters to fade in one by one gradually from left to right.  I would like an example or another site that uses this functionality.

Comment: What didn't work about your first try?

Comment: Horribly unclear and vague question, you didn't even mention what sort of effect you want, how would you expect people to help you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: animate hide letters randomly but with equal intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48351445/jquery-animate-hide-letters-randomly-but-with-equal-intervals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/ to fade in every single letter?

then use http://api.jquery.com/animate/ to let them fly around.

then finaly use http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/ to fade out every single letter.

and then set a delay for the document so that the animationqueue starts over each 10 or more seconds.

Comment: yes doing like,
 <div id="testDiv">test</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('#testDiv').delay(1000).fadeIn(500).delay(4000).fadeOut(500);
      });
  
</script>

Comment: Have a look at [Lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com/) for an easy way to wrap your text in markup.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said what kind of effect you want and you are mildly unclear. But here's a [jquery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ghostType) that makes a block of text appear to be typed into the page.

It's called [ghostType.com](http://ghosttype.com/)

Comment: Thanks, effects like make bigger then again Smaller and so on.Is it possible?

Comment: Possible, but jQuery makes that very very easy. Have you tried coding it yourself ?