# jQuery: animate hide letters randomly but with equal intervals

Tags: jquery, animation, requestanimationframe

I have two questions.

- Why the animation that makes the letters randomly disappear doesn't follow the same speed for all the letters? The animation is not fluid.
- How can I make the animation works on the opposite side? When I hide the div with .hide() and I try to make it appear with opacity this won't work. I tried different solution already but really nothing makes the div appear.

Code:

```js
function wow1 () {

 var mail1 = $(".mailFirst h2");
 var letters = mail1.children();

 setInterval(function() {
  letters.eq(Math.random()*letters.length |0).animate({opacity:0},500);
 },500);
}

$(document).ready(wow1);
```

```css
.mailFirst {position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mailFirst">
  <h2> 
    <span> @ </span>
    <span> E </span>
    <span> - </span>
    <span> M </span>
    <span> a </span>
    <span> i </span>
    <span> l </span>
    <span> @ </span>
  </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I apologise for this, I will not use this forbidden word anymore in my question. The only reason why I used those word has been to explain that was an urgent problem for me not to get as much people as possible. Thank you anyway for your help.

Comment: It's not that it's a forbidden word as such - just an encouragement to use basic manners. We get a lot of people who beg and plead here, and the levels of entitlement exhibited towards **volunteer** helpers is something of a problem that needs to be challenged. If I have helped someone understand the (obvious) point that questions are answered at leisure here, I will regard that as a success.

Comment: On the occasions I am advised to "mind my own business", I find that the action I am asked to take is anti-community. If people assert the right to cajole volunteers, they will also assert the right to say what will happen if their deadlines are not met (they will lose their job, they will lose an important client, they will fail their course, etc). We get all that here, and it is an unacceptable emotional blackmail. So... refrain from adding it please!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Problems

The problems in your script includes one major fault is that you are generating random numbers unaware from the fact that the generated number will be used to select a `span` and hide it and it needs to be a valid index, and what actually happens that it keeps on generating numbers which may occur twice, in which case it will try to hide the hidden letter again, and the waiting period of trying to find the valid index which is also not hidden it sometime takes less time or sometimes more. so that is the real reason behind the hiding time not being the same.

Secondly, you are just running the animation and that's it there is no stopping of the script it is continuously running and loading your browser along with `setInterrval()` which alone is not known to have mercy on your browser even if it is minimized or tab switched, you need to stop it once all spans are hidden.

### What to do

1. Select the elements you have to hide.
2. Get elements in an array using [`.toArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/) in a var say `elemArray`
3. Start generating the random number and validate if it is a valid index for the `elemArray` if not call it recursively until you find a valid index between the range `[0 - elemArray.length]`.
4. When you find a valid index hide the element on that index and use `splice` to remove that element from the `elemArray` in this way you will hide every element once and into a random sequence
5. Now about animations, Say Hello to [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

   `requestAnimationFrame` function that allows you to create smooth and fluid animations in JavaScript without you actually having to worry about making it smooth and fluid. Just add a few calls to `requestAnimationFrame` and your browser takes care of the rest. That's it. and it also helps to control the factors such as your laptop/ phone/tablet going into battery mode and halving its performance reduced. Factors such as another tab taking focus. Read More **[`Here`](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/animating_with_requestAnimationFrame.htm)**
6. And in the end, you have to stop the animation too so use the brother of `requestAnimationFrame` function which is [`cancelAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/cancelAnimationFrame)

see below I created a demo for you hope it helps you out.

```js
var framesPerSecond = 10;
var letters = $(".mailFirst>h2 span");
var elemArray = letters.toArray();
// store your requestAnimatFrame request ID value
var requestId;

//the animation function
function animate() {
  setTimeout(function() {

    //save the id returned from the function to use it 
    //for canceling or stopping the animation

    requestId = requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    // animating/drawing code goes here
    hideRandomWord();

    //check if there are no more elements left to hide
    if (!elemArray.length) {
      stopAnimation(requestId);
    }
  }, 2000 / framesPerSecond);
}
//start animation
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

//function to hide a character / word
function hideRandomWord() {

  var min = 0;
  var max = Math.floor(elemArray.length);

  //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  
  //if elements array is not empty
  if (elemArray.length) {

    //if the generated index is a valid index for the elements array
    if (typeof elemArray[rand] !== 'undefined') {

     //animate opacity 
      $(elemArray[rand]).animate({
        opacity: 0
      });
      //remove the element from the elements array
      elemArray.splice(rand, 1);
    } else {
      //call recursively it self if not valid index generated
      hideRandomWord();
    }
  }
}

function stopAnimation(requestId) {
  // use the requestID to cancel the requestAnimationFrame call
  cancelAnimationFrame(requestId);
}
```

```css
.mailFirst {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mailFirst">
  <h2>
    <span> @ </span>
    <span> E </span>
    <span> - </span>
    <span> M </span>
    <span> a </span>
    <span> i </span>
    <span> l </span>
    <span> @ </span>
  </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Honestly I just hope you are a teacher, otherwise your talent would be waste. Perfect complete explanation. Thank you so much for your patience I really appreciate it!

Comment: :) thanks for the compliments , glad i was able to help you out

Comment: one thing more if you like to make it continuous animation you might need to modify the code inside condition `if (!elemArray.length) {` within the `animate()` function and replace the `stopAnimation(requestId);` with the logic to reset the `opacity` of all items to `1` and refill the `elemArray` again. OR you can do all this inside the else part in  `hideRandomWord()` too and remove the condition from `animate()` altogether ;) @Marcello

Answer (score 1):

The first problem, the uneven hiding of the letters, is due to the nature of your random function.
It looks for a letter to randomly hide, hides it and selects another. But the random selection still includes letters that have already been hidden, so it's just hiding them again - which is an operation you can't see so it looks like nothing is happening.
You need to remove the letters from the array as they get hidden so they no longer get included in the random selection.

Comment: Thank you Steve, perfect explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Steve has explained it well but here is the code for it.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .mailFirst {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mailFirst">
    <h2>
      <span> @ </span>
      <span> E </span>
      <span> - </span>
      <span> M </span>
      <span> a </span>
      <span> i </span>
      <span> l </span>
      <span> @ </span>
    </h2>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var mail1 = $(".mailFirst h2");
    var letters = mail1.children();
    var numberOfSpans = letters.length;
    var hiddenSpans = 0;

    function changeOpacity() {
    
      setTimeout(
        function() {
          var ind;
          var opc;

          do {
            var ind = (Math.random() * letters.length | 0);
            var opc = Number(letters.eq(ind).css("opacity"));
            console.log("index: " + ind + " and opc: " + opc);
          } while (opc != 1)

          letters.eq(ind).animate({
            opacity: 0
          }, 500);

          hiddenSpans++;
          if (hiddenSpans < numberOfSpans) {
            changeOpacity();
          }
        }, 500
      );
    }
    $(document).ready(changeOpacity);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Adam for your time.